# How would one 'falsify' data collected of you by companies using software?

Tags: data, web

Since we live in a world where basically all your web activity is being tracked by some company or your ISP. I was wondering how to 'falsify' the data they collect.

For instance by having software go to page A and performed X, Y and Z actions. if user goes to page A and performs B, F and G actions. In this case the real 'data' would be that user went to company's website and performed B, F and G actions which we falsify by having software make different actions on the same site. The real data is still being collected but not accurate anymore since from the companies POV the user also performed other actions.

How would be a good way to do this and what are things to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, obfuscating your actual activity with such a “smoke and mirrors” approach does make it harder to track you. However, this is likely to have little practical effect.

- The clickstream will still include your actual activity.
- The simulated and actual activity might either be correlated and therefore still useful, or uncorrelated and therefore easy to separate.
- Online behavioural advertising doesn't have to have a correct profile on everyone all the time. It is still profitable if this profiling is sufficiently accurate most of the time. You as an individual can defend yourself, but this has little effect on a societal level.

More practical digital self-defense approaches include:

- denying data flows to trackers, e.g. by using ad blockers. Some information can be denied to ISPs by tunnelling to a VPN, but then you have to trust the VPN instead (I trust my ISP more than a VPN provider). Another technique for denying a clickstream to an ISP is to use DNS over HTTPS. However, the lack of a signal is also a signal, see the rise of adblocker-blockers.

  - where possible, one can try to opt out from data aggregators, e.g. by disabling ad personalization in a Google account.
- sharing identifiers with other people in order to resist fingerprinting. You can have your browser fingerprint estimated at https://panopticlick.eff.org/. Despite aiming for a privacy-enhanced browser configuration, I'm easily identifiable by my installed fonts or by the combination of “Windows NT” in the user agent when actually running Linux.
- frequently switching identifiers, to avoid larger profiles from being assembled. Of course, “session stitching” is easily done when a strong identifier connects two fingerprints, e.g. by logging into the same account.

There are existing technical solutions such as adblockers, Pi-holes, VPNs and so on, all with various tradeoffs. If you're trying to simulate browsing activity, this could be done as a separate appliance that runs a (headless) browser (but which might be easy to detect as inauthentic behaviour), or as a browser addon (which has access to more identifiers such as your cookies but has limitations in what can be done). I would instead suggest thinking about ways to separate different aspects of your online identity from each other, and ways to select which services you entrust with your data (like with the ISP–VPN tradeoff mentioned previously).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I stilll have a minor side question though. If I understand correctly, a Pi-Hole just filters out ads. Does a Pi-Hole do anything for your privacy as well?

Comment: @BasVelden The problem with ads is less the visual annoyance but that ads are used to track and profile you. Pi-Hole also blocks many trackers. The connecting element is “online behavioural advertising”: to give you personalized ads (that have higher probability of being clicked by you) the ad networks need a profile on you. Part of this profile is remembering on which websites you viewed their ads. Thus, blocking all third-party ads is an important step to more privacy.